# Maximum of a fitted Gaussian in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, max, curve-fitting, gaussian

I need to find the maximum of a Gaussian I have fitted, below is my sample code (ignore the fact that it is a horrible fit to the Gaussian, they were just two spare matrices I had kicking around in my variables tray)

```
x=[10;2;6;1;7;5;3;4;8;9];
z1=[0;0;0;0;0;6;7;8;9;10];
cf1=fit(x,z1,'gauss1');
plot(x,z1,'.k')
hold on
plot(cf1,'r')
```

Any help you guys could give me would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Oh, I forgot to mention that I have to do this without the curve fitting tool as I need to use this maximum in a future calculation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's pretty basic math. Look at the output of

```
>> cf1

cf1 = 
     General model Gauss1:
     cf1(x) =  a1*exp(-((x-b1)/c1)^2)
     Coefficients (with 95% confidence bounds):
       a1 =       5.187  (-0.4711, 10.85)
       b1 =       6.834  (-0.768, 14.44)
       c1 =       5.945  (-8.833, 20.72)
```

Now, armed with [the wikipedia article on Gaussians](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution), it's trivial to find the maximum:

```
maximum_x = cf1.b1;
maximum_y = cf1.a1;
```

Same will be true for whatever other tool you use to fit the same function -- the coefficients `a1` and `b1` define the `y` and `x` locations of the maximum, respectively.

Comment: Thanks, I thought I was missing something extremely simple.